# Loading CSV file Polygon Column to Microsoft SQL Table

Tags: qgis, polygon, sql-server, geopandas, import

How do I import a polygon from CSV to SQL?

I have attempted to use the SQL Import and Export wizard to load it in as varchar(max) and then convert using `geography::Parse(column)` as well as `Geography::STGeomFromText(column,CRS)` but in both cases it failed with an error that 'Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.'

For more context, the data flow so far as been from shapefile to geodataframe using `geopandas`, then converted to df using `pandas` and sent to '.csv' using `pandas`

Comment: What coordinate system is your polygon data in? If not in LAT/LON (WGS84), then the geography column won't work. If you have data in another coordinate system, you should use the geometry type.

Comment: Also, if you have QGIS, take a look at this script - it works pretty well for us when loading a shapefile to mssql server https://github.com/dpsspatial/Installation-Instructions/blob/master/shp2mssql_osgeo4w.py

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. I'm seeing now the start of my problem. I believe the CRS used is 3857 if I am following you correctly, or WGS 84/Pseudo-Mercator... the shame is that as little as I know so far, the one thing I had been consistently doing is switching to EPSG:4326 (WSG84) and somehow this got set to its default

Comment: The GEOGRAPHY data type won't allow for SRID:3857, but you can load that into GEOMETRY data type...

Comment: That I did! And I thought I was set, but when comparing my latitude and longitude in my geometric polygon. . .and, unless I'm mistaken, that told me I shouldn't have. . . and I don't imagine there's reprojection options for latitude, longitude to x,y in sql without losing precision, is there?

Comment: I believe that you've solved my problem, though. I am going to reupload and even attempt using your script. Will reply if all is successful! thanks again!

Comment: OK great - keep in touch, and my email is in my profile if you want to get in touch. Thanks!!

Comment: just saw your other question - mssql doesn't have any re-projection functions, and i don't trust the 'hacks' out there...

Comment: Thank you! That fixed me up. I did not get to use the script yet because at this point I had worked Python into the solution and had been pretty cozy with quick-fixing that way. Look forward to implementing it directly that way though, thanks again.

Comment: Good stuff... we use SQL server spatial extensively, so keep in touch if you have any other issues! (but we use PostGIS as the starting point for all our spatial data - invaluable for modeling spatial data for a relational database, but understanding the constraints organizations have in having to use MSSQL server...)